# Mariadb support rtree index on innodb soon?

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, mariadb

I was looking through mariadb bug list online (https://mariadb.atlassian.net/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?rapidView=24&projectKey=MDEV), but I am unfamiliar with JIRA so I am not sure exactly what I am doing when looking, but will mariadb in the near future (few months) support rtree indexing for innodb? MySQL 5.7 has introduced boost libraries alongside rtree indexes to innodb quite a while ago, but I can't find any information on maria db including this into their build

Comment: There is some lag in MariaDB for folding in changes generated by Oracle.  I think MariaDB is still working on getting 5.6 fixes/features folded in, either directly or via equivalent code.